# Unable to execute dex: GC overhead limit exceeded in Google Play Services?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-play-services

I am stuck in last two days and try to run the project and also i changed many values but still same error with google play services. i am using eclipse juno 64bit and using alot of APIs jar and projects google play services is one of them. This is my below file can any body help me please how to get rid of this dam problem. its waste my lot of time.

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.adtproduct
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-Xms512m
-Xmx1024m
```

Comment: please start using android studio, eclipse is dead for android development

Comment: ok fine but how i configure this for now

Comment: using "alot of APIs jar and projects" may mean you are hitting the 65k limit.  Review this: https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html and see if it helps